# WPF XamlReader.Parse Dynamic UI xml Namespaces

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception, xamlreader

I've a dynamic WPF UI wich is described in xaml.

The xaml can be seen below. My Problem is that my Custom namespaces aren't resolved automatically,

To get the xaml loaded I have to set **each** assembly with its namespace to the parser context like this

```
var context = new ParserContext();
context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[] { });      

context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("Custom","http://myCompany.de");
context.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("http://myCompany.de","FooNamespace","FooAssemblyName");
```

Isn't there a better way? I need this dynamically. And I don't want to scan the app domain.

How is this done in the normal "System Xaml Reader" ?

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:Custom="http://myCompany.de"
    x:Class="Foo.Container" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Custom:FooViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clr-Namespace URI's without an assembly mentioned only work as compiled Xaml.
```

But in case you provide assembly with namespaces like - `";assembly=AssemblyName"` suffix to your Uri, it will be parse successfully.

But in your case `xmlns:Custom="http://myCompany.de"`, you can't add assembly reference. so, i think the only way out is to add the mapping manually for this case.

And for custom namespaces belonging to your project, you can use the `assembly` suffix to get them parse.

Comment: Thanks for info in most of the cases I could use the syntax with the assembly name without url. For Thirdparty controls I wil ladd the reference